# How to add for loop value to div tag id in python flask?

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I have a `flask project` in which I need to add each value of `i` from a `for-loop` into the `div` tags `class`.

Something like :

```
{% for i in range(5) %}

    <div class="cls{{ i }}">

{% endfor %}
```

In each looping it should give

```
 cls1,cls2,cls3 etc
```

Comment: What's the issue with doing `<div class="cls{{ i+1 }}">`? It'll give `cls1`, `cls2` etc.., instead of `cls0`, `cls1` ... Is that what you need?

Comment: but only first div is visible.. actually i am trying to display a table inside each div

Comment: Can you then show us the HTML structure? This will generate 5 divs with class attributes as `cls1`, `cls1` .... `cls5` when you change it to `{{ i+1 }}`

Comment: hey.its working... srry

Comment: Perfect, I just posted the same as an answer for those who might stumble across this post in the future. Feel free to upvote/accept it. All the best

Comment: i got negative vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jinja templating allows you to perform mathematic operations inside the `{{}}` So for getting your class attributes as `cls1`, `cls2`, .. `cls5` you could just do the following

```
{% for i in range(5) %}
    <div class="cls{{ i+1 }}">
{% endfor %}
```

Which will render the following:

```
<div class="cls1">
<div class="cls2">
<div class="cls3">
<div class="cls4">
<div class="cls5">
```